# How to speed up a mysql query which have lot of subqueries

Tags: php, mysql, web

I'm developing an distributor system which can generate summary reports in different formats.I have been used sub-queries to get a sum of a specific column value in different criteria.Using sub-queries have slowed down generating the result. I want to know is there any way to speed up my query? or how can I optimize my query? Here is my query.

```
SELECT 
    ar.area_name,
    wk.workshop_name,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no not like '000W%'
                and part_no like 'TE%'
                and date_edit = '2014-02-13')
        group by wk.workshop_name) as normal_tata_daily,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no not like '000W%'
                and part_no like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-13'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as normal_tata_commulative,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no not like '000W%'
                and part_no like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2013-04-01' and '2014-03-01'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as normal_tata_overall,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no not like '000W%'
                and part_no not like 'TE%'
                and date_edit = '2014-02-13')
        group by wk.workshop_name) as normal_non_tata_daily,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no not like '000W%'
                and part_no not like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-13'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as normal_non_tata_commulative,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no not like '000W%'
                and part_no not like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2013-04-01' and '2014-03-01'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as normal_non_tata_overall,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no like '000W%'
                and part_no like 'TE%'
                and date_edit = '2014-02-13')
        group by wk.workshop_name) as warrenty_tata_daily,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no like '000W%'
                and part_no like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-13'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as warrenty_tata_commulative,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no like '000W%'
                and part_no like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2013-04-01' and '2014-03-01'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as warrenty_tata_overall,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no like '000W%'
                and part_no not like 'TE%'
                and date_edit = '2014-02-13')
        group by wk.workshop_name) as warrenty_non_tata_daily,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no like '000W%'
                and part_no not like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-13'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as warrenty_non_tata_commulative,
    (select 
            round(sum(selling_val), 2) as total
        from
            tbl_all_sales
        where
            (area_id = ar.area_id
                and de = wk.identifier
                and status = 1
                and acc_no like '000W%'
                and part_no not like 'TE%'
                and (date(date_edit) between '2013-04-01' and '2014-03-01'))
        group by wk.workshop_name) as warrenty_non_tata_overall
from
    tbl_workshop wk
        inner join
    tbl_area ar ON wk.area_id = ar.area_id
        left join
    tbl_all_sales als ON ar.area_id = als.area_id
group by wk.workshop_name
order by ar.area_name
```

Thank full any of your wise answers..

Comment: What indexes do you have? We need to see your indexes and the output of an `EXPLAIN` statement.

Comment: I think the problem actually lies in the database design, there.

Comment: You probably just need to build tables to store some of your aggregated data for reporting purposes.

Comment: this query take at least 2.30 or 3 mins to execute..I want to know will it be a very big issue on the performance of the system??

Comment: Why not change that query to joining the same table (per number of sub selects you do) with an alias, and then in only one select pull out `round(sum(table_alias.selling_val), 2) as total` and then in the where just make it and `(date(table_alias.date_edit) between '2013-04-01' and '2014-03-01'))` for each of the different date fields

Comment: Any particular reason to left join `tbl_all_sales` (aliased as `als`) at the end when not using any fields from it?

Comment: btw this is a really bad query.. because those selects are triggering per row in your whole table --- also plz post some sample data... we can build a schema and do different things with it.

Comment: here i am connecting another system with my system.I have placed tbl_all_sales to take all the transactions from the other system.In this table my foreign_key is area_id.also I have a tbl_workshop in my system.Im trying here to get 4 different sales types in 3 date ranges.

Comment: can you post some sample data? it would be really helpful

Comment: @John Offensive? What? I can hear the "flag declined" clicks from a thousand miles away.